# Can't get Maven working with Nexus OSS

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, nexus

I just installed Nexus 2.1.2 on one of our dev machines, and I want to use it as a proxy for the central repository, and as the internal repository for our snapshots and releases.  I tried to follow the examples from Sonatype on how to set this up, but I keep getting a bunch of errors in my POM (I'm using Eclipse and m2e).  Here are the errors:

> No plugin found for prefix 'war' in the current project and in the
> plugin groups [] available from the repositories [local
> (C:\Users\jwolinsk.m2\repository), nexus
> (http://xxxxxxdev9:8081/nexus/content/repositories/groups/public)]
>
> No plugin found for prefix 'war' in the current project and in the
> plugin groups [] available from the repositories [local
> (C:\Users\jwolinsk.m2\repository), nexus
> (http://jc1lkddev9:8081/nexus/content/  repositories/groups/public)]

Here is my settings.xml:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <port>8080</port>
            <host>xxxxprxy2</host>
            <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
            <id>httpProxy</id>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://xxxxxdev9:8081/nexus/content/repositories/groups/public</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>local</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

And here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ks</groupId>
    <artifactId>kdweb</artifactId>
    <name>kdweb</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
        <version>7</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ks</groupId>
            <artifactId>acommons</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ks</groupId>
            <artifactId>aggregation-common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ks.thirdparty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jconn</artifactId>
            <version>3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ks</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework-common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ks.thirdparty</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6_g</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this  :

```
<mirror>
    <id>nexus-local</id>
    <url>http://xxxxxx:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
<mirror>
    <id>nexus.snapshots-local</id>
    <url>http://xxxxx:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    <mirrorOf>snapshots</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

Otherwise, have you check that in your Nexus, libraries are correctly download.
You may have a network problem in nexus so it cannot access web and download plugins, dependencies.

If you are behind a proxy you need to configure it in Nexus :

Administration --> Server --> Default HTTP Proxy settings

[image]

Comment: Do you know how I can tell if nexus is having trouble reaching the web? If I try to "browse remote" on the central repository, I don't see anything.

Comment: If browse remote is not working your Nexus server is not able to reach the central repo. Log into it on e.g. the command line and try to ping central and configure the proxy as mentioned in the answer. But dont take those changes to settings.xml.

Comment: Is there a way to add the proxy settings via Environment variables? It looks like the server does not honor "http_proxy" settings...

Answer (score 0):

To check that your nexus OSS installation can reach the web, you can login as admin, then open the `Repositories` (clicking on the left side "Repositories"), then select the default `Central` repository, then in the lower view, select the `Browse Remote` tab, and finally select the `Refresh` button.  It should show you all the components available in the Central repository (i.e. your nexus can connect to the web).  (note: this contribution should have been a comment, but I am not allowed to comment yet).

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of the proxy section in your settings first. Then ensure that you can connect to your Nexus instance from your dev machine. And lastly ensure that your Nexus can reach the central repo and anything else you want to proxy by configuring the proxy settings in Nexus.

Nexus will not take into account the proxy settings from your settings.xml (since they are local to your machine and not your Nexus server that would not make sense).